# Error in syntax on mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql query that I'm running with php, but I don't really know whats wrong on it, can somebody help me?

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total FROM OrderDetails 
GROUP BY OrderID WHERE ProductID BETWEEN 11 AND 14;
```

Comment: Do you get an error, what does it say?

Comment: @randomizer " `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'OrderID WHERE ProductID BETWEEN 11 AND 14' `" 


I'm running my mysql query here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_sum

Comment: Like Puneet statet below, your GROUP BY statement should be placed at the end of your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following :-

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total 
FROM OrderDetails 
WHERE ProductID BETWEEN 11 AND 14 
GROUP BY OrderID;
```